# Read string from another JS file

Tags: jquery

i have test1.js which contains JSON string like following
{"SearchMoreText": "View more results"}

Now, i have another test2.js file where i need this string, i can't assign above string to any variable as i need to read test1.js from server side and need to create dictionary object. i need to read this string from test2.js and put it to js variable so i can access this client side too.

test1. js

```
{
"foodtabsettings": [  
  {"tabText": "Add Meal Plan", "tabOrder": "1", "tabID": "QuickListNav_5" }, 
  { "tabText": "Search Foods", "tabOrder": "2", "tabID": "QuickListNav_1" },
  { "tabText": "My Favorites", "tabOrder": "3", "tabID": "QuickListNav_3" },
  { "tabText": "Created by Me", "tabOrder": "4", "tabID": "QuickListNav_4" }
]}
```

in test2.js

```
(function() {
 var settings = Need string from test1.js
}();
```

Any help?

Comment: is it really anonymous function in the other script?

Answer (score 4):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON('test1.js', function(data) {
  var settings = data['foodtabsettings']; // an array
  // do something
}
```

Comment: both js file is in same directory, do i need to provide path?

Comment: If they're in the same directory, no.